# Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ImportFilepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="XML Files (*.xml), *.xsd", _
        Title:="Choose File", MultiSelect:=False)
 With ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("data-set_Map")
 .AdjustColumnWidth = False
 End With
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("data-set_Map").Import URL:= _
ImportFilepath

End Sub
```

Problem: This code used for import xml file data into excel cell.This is working correctly at first time but when I am going to import on second time the I was getting this error "Run-time error '1004'".

Comment: At which line to you get the error?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("data-set_Map").Import URL:= _
ImportFilepath

Comment: I got error in this line ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("data-set_Map").Import URL:= _
ImportFilepath

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but because I've encountered the same problem:
In my case, the error was generated by the activation of the protect sheet feature.
After I unprotect sheet before XML Import (and protect after) works well!